# Plutonium element configuration

Tags: electronic-configuration

For Plutonium 94 when I do it's element configuration I get

```
1s2-2s2-2p6-3s2-3p6-4s2--3d10-4p6-5s2-4d10-5p6-6s2-4f14-5d10-6p6-7s2-5f6
```

I found on [this site](https://sciencestruck.com/electron-configuration-chart-for-all-elements-in-periodic-table) that I'm correct however when I look it up on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium) it says

`[Rn] 5f6-7s2`

I know this is the short way to write it but I thought it would

```
[Rn] 7s2-5f6
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration may help some. Yes, a different page on Wikipedia...